# Motor sizing calculation

Tags: induction-motor

I have built a machine. The main machine shaft rotates when 4KG force is applied at a 1 foot distance from the center of the shaft. I want my machine to run at 1500 RPM.

How do I select the right motor (induction motor) size in terms of horsepower?

Comment: You have the distance and the force so there is your torque needed. For power, you multiply torque with rotational speed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your specifications to common units of measurement. Then use one of the common equations:

Horsepower = Torque (Foot-Pounds) X RPM / 5250

Kilowatts = Torque (Newton-Meters) X RPM / 9549

Answer (score 0):

This is first a mechanical problem, not an electrical one yet. You need to determine the required mechanical torque, then once you know that, the motor selection is easy. Determining mechanical torque requirements is not an electrical engineering discipline.